# Getting Auth Error in AWS amplify with Existing AWS appsync graphql api

Tags: amazon-web-services, graphql, openid-connect, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

I am using my existing AWS appsync api in a new AWS amplify project. I followed the documentation for setting up the amplify project and using exisitng grapql api withit. when i try to make graphql api request using aws-amplify API module i am getting error "AuthError: Error: Amplify has not been configured correctly.
The configuration object is missing required auth properties"

i tried it with angular and react FE but getting same error.

Note i am using OPENID_CONNECT as athentication type for my appsync api and i am able to send request using postman and through aws console, and its working.

Amplify.configure(awsexport);  ->  awsexport contains graphql api endpoint, project region, authmethod, appsync api region.

same like this.
[image]

this image also shows a comment which says we have to "// Before calling API.graphql(...) is required to do Auth.federatedSignIn(...) check authentication guide for details."

Auth.federatedSignIn works for aws congnito users but not for openidconnect users. if this solves the problem, i may need example.

what can be the possible solution?

Thanks

i was following the documentation provided by aws and checked several threads on stackoverflow but did not find proper solution.